# Looking for 10" bamboo steamer that will last!

Tags: equipment

I've owned quite a few different bamboo steamers. First one I bought many years ago and it lasted many years. Last few I have purchased did not. We're talking normal use, hand washing only. Seems like they are made ever more cheaply and none of them hold up well.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can ensure that the next one purchased will be durable and hold up well? Is there anything in particular I should be looking for/at?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I edited your question in the hopes that it will not be closed. We are a strict Q & A site unlike most discussion forums found on the internet. We hope you will stick around and invite you to view our Tour and Help pages to learn more about the site. Both can be found under the question mark (?) dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: can you tell us what brands you have tried and where you have looked. I've seen several on Amazon that "look good" but I don't know if you have already looked there, etc.

Comment: @CosCallis : I've had bad luck buying kitchenware stuff on Amazon lately.  In the case of a couple of "Norpro" oil sprayers, it wasn't until after I had filled one that I realized it didn't match the picture, and the design made it functionally useless (the tube to suck up oil didn't reach the bottom of the container, much less one of the corners).  I ended up buying an RSVP one in a kitchenwares store where I could be sure of what I was buying

Comment: Try the Wok Shop in San Francisco. http://wokshop.stores.yahoo.net/ I've bought a carbon steel wok from them and a few utensils. Good quality, inexpensive and good service.

Comment: To answer your questions, I bought one at Bed Bath and Beyond that held up a few years, and I believe the next couple were from Amazon.  One was VonShef and one was one of the "Chen" brands. If I had to guess I suspect they are all made in the same factory in China. To be fair we use ours nearly every time we cook a meal. We love steaming veggies in them.

Comment: In the end we decided to try a new direction and bought a stainless steel steamer pot. It has 3 pieces and a lid, with a pasta strainer and a veg strainer that fits into that. More flexible because you can still steam 2 levels of veg or you can use it as a convenient way to boil your pasta, or as a regular pot.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in the trade, we don't "hand wash" the bamboo steamers, we just let it sit in hot water for a bit and rinse it off. Try not to scrub it either.

Obviously, most of us aren't steaming things on a commercial scale, so I recommend placing a sheet of either baking, parchment or butter paper below the food when you steam. The sheet acts as a protective layer, preventing food from sticking to the bottom and prevents the steamer from getting too dirty (stuck bits of food, etc)  which also makes cleaning easier as you only discard the sheet. You don't need to change it after every item steamed, only when you feel its necessary